# knitr::kable does not escape special character $ correctly in the string data when knitring to html (to PDF is okay)

Tags: html, r, knitr, special-characters, kable

With $-signs in the data knitr::kable is confused. The data are shown as if they were meant to be in math-mode. Funny enough, knitr to PDF does not show this effect.

I tried to escape the dollar-sign with backslash (even tried to use up to four backslashes), to use chunk-option "markup" for results, to set off auto-escaping in kable, or to use Hex-Unicode instead of the character. Nothing helped.
Any further ideas are very welcome.

I use Rstudio to knitr either as HTML or as PDF. Here is my MWE from my *.Rmd:

````
---
title: MWE knitr::kable does not escape special character $ correctly in the string data when knitring to html (to PDF is okay)
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document: default
---

    ```{r UNESCAPED , eval=TRUE ,  echo=FALSE , tidy=TRUE, message=FALSE , warning=FALSE , results='asis'}
    
    
    
    library ("knitr")
    library("kableExtra")#not needed but helpful to see the problem
    library("tidyverse")#not needed but helpful to see the problem
    
    data <- data.frame(stringVar=c("$1$","$2$"))
    #escaping $ shows error message:
    #data <- data.frame(stringVar=c("\$1\$","\$2\$"))
    
    if (knitr::is_html_output())
    {
      knitr::kable(data, row.names = TRUE, format = "html" , escape = TRUE)%>% #same effect with escape=FALSE
        kable_styling( "striped")#same effect without kable_styling
      #last cell is rendered in math mode
    }else{
      knitr::kable(data, format="latex", longtable=T, booktabs = T, linesep = "", row.names = TRUE, escape = TRUE) %>%
        kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped")) 
      #last cell is rendered as expected
    }#end of if
    
    
    ```
````

Comment: If using \ to escape: you would need one to escape the dollar sign and then a second to escape the first backslash.  Using `data <- data.frame(stringVar=c("\\$1\\$","\\$2\\$"))` seems to work for the HTML table.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I got confused with the number of backslashes in replacement. The solution of user12728748 is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can make it work by using backticks:

**Edit:**

@aosmith is correct - double escape is the better answer, as it does not render it with background shading

````
---
title: MWE knitr::kable does not escape special character $ correctly in the string data when knitring to html (to PDF is okay)
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r UNESCAPED , eval=TRUE ,  echo=FALSE , tidy=TRUE, message=FALSE , warning=FALSE , results='asis'}
    
    
    
    library ("knitr")
    library("kableExtra")#not needed but helpful to see the problem
    library("tidyverse")#not needed but helpful to see the problem
    
    data <- data.frame(stringVar=c("$1$","$2$"))
    
    if (knitr::is_html_output())
    {
     #   data %>% mutate_all( stringr::str_replace_all, pattern=fixed("$"), replacement="`$`") %>% 
data %>% mutate_all( stringr::str_replace_all, pattern=fixed("$"), replacement="\\$") %>% 
      knitr::kable( row.names = TRUE, format = "html" , escape = FALSE) %>% #same effect with escape=FALSE
        kable_styling( "striped")#same effect without kable_styling
      #last cell is rendered in math mode
    }else{
      knitr::kable(data, format="latex", longtable=T, booktabs = T, linesep = "", row.names = TRUE, escape = TRUE) %>%
        kable_styling(latex_options =c("striped")) 
      #last cell is rendered as expected
    }#end of if
    
    
```
````

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with the number of backslashes. Your code is very clear. What I tried was:  gsub(pattern="\\$", replacement="\\\\\\$", x=data$stringVar) (But I used the wrong number of backticks then.)